# Prevent Outlook from selecting emails by itself

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

When I open my inbox in Outlook the first email will be selected.

Is there any setting or plugin that can do so that no email is selected by Outlook, only by me?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is pretty drastic.

Click on the "root" folder of your default account. You should see the "Outlook Today" page. Click on the customise button and choose the startup option so that Outlook always starts on that page.

It is possible, though, that the reason you don't want anything selected is that, by default, Outlook will mark it read. You should note, if that *is* the reason, that you can change that behaviour in the options.

Comment: To change to the "Outlook Today" page does not solve the issue with Outlook selecting emails by itself when opening the inbox. Is there an option to tell Outlook to not select emails by itself? Where?

Comment: Nope. The best you can do is to tell outlook not to mark the mail read simply because you landed on it while the preview pane is open.